# Duplicate of TwoLinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Im trying to find duplicates in that 2 `linkedlists` but I don't know where is the problem in here. Output is keep showing me nothing. I'll find the duplicate of these two `LinkedLists` and after that I'll put it to another LinkedList.

```
public class TwoLinkedList {

    public static void Find(){
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                if(List.get(i)==List2.get(j)){
                    System.out.println(List.get(i));                
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void add(int element){
        List.add(element);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List.add(5);
        List.add(4);
        List.add(7);
        List2.add(6);
        List2.add(15);
        List2.add(4);
        Find();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `return` statement from below method. It will work.

```
public static void Find(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        if(List.get(i)==List2.get(j)){
            System.out.println(List.get(i));                
        }
        else {
            return;}
        }
    }
        }
```